# Protecting .jar with .htaccess?

Tags: java, php

I want to prevent decompiling for my game client.
Is there a option I can some how protect the .jar file with .htaccess or any other method so the client (Browsing user, that loads the client via a applet) won't be able to get the file & decompile it.

I always wondered if there is a solution for this, is there? Maybe creating a crypt code, and whenever the server tries to get the client jar, it will send a crypt code via GET, if the crypt code matches, it will load the client from that page, I don't know, there should be a solution ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a browser to execute an applet, it needs to download the jar file containing the applet code. An if it downloads it, it's available for decompilation. To protect you against that, you can obfuscate the byte-code, or not use an applet at all, and simply use a traditional web application, where the code is at server-side, and the client only see HTML and JavaScript code.

Comment: How is that possible? then the user can't load the client right?

Comment: you can obfuscate the byte-code, or not use an applet at all, and simply use a traditional web application, where the code is at server-side, and the client only see HTML and JavaScript code.

Comment: obfuscating the byte-code just consists in replacing class, methods and variable names with meaningless values (like a1, a2, a3, etc.), making the code still functional, but very hard to read and understand.

Comment: "just make it so they have to use it in the browser
then check if they are accessing it from our url" 

Could that work?

Comment: "you could also make php create a session variable with a hash in and check if that hah is present and matches our hashing algorithm"

Comment: The point of decompiling code is to be able to modify it, remove any security measure it contains, and recompile it to make it runnable anywhere you want. If you don't want users to have access to your byte-code, then don't use an applet. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

No. You could stop the browser getting the file, but then it would be unable to run it.

> Maybe creating a crypt code, and whenever the server tries to get the client jar, it will send a crypt code via GET, if the crypt code matches, it will load the client from that page,

The user could see the code and still get the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is *nothing* you can do to prevent the user getting hold of the unencrypted bytecodes.

**NOTHING.**

The user's machine needs the applet's bytecodes in unencrypted form in order to execute them.  Since a user (with sufficient knowledge) has totally control over what his machine does, you can assume that control will extend to allowing him / her to intercept the bytecodes at some point where they have been decrypted.

And if the user can intercept the applet's bytecodes, then he / she can *change* them to defeat any clever stuff you put into the code.  And that includes changing the bytecodes to defeat any measure that you use to detect changes to the bytecodes.

> "just make it so they have to use it in the browser then check if they are accessing it from our url" Could that work?

Nope.  The user can modify the applet to remove that check.

> "you could also make php create a session variable with a hash in and check if that hah is present and matches our hashing algorithm"

Nope.  The user can modify the applet to remove that check too.

> I don't know, there should be a solution ?

Unfortunately, there is no practical solution ... apart from running everything that needs protecting on the server side.

By the way, this problem is not unique to Java.  Someone with the technical knowledge and the motivation can defeat any tamper protection measures in Javascript too, or even in native code plugins that you get the user to install (if he is foolish enough).

Comment: How about running everything server sided, then loading the client via javascript, HTML?

Will that 'LAG' for the user?

Comment: That depends on the application.  But, probably the answer is Yes the user will experience "lag".